# Python dictionary removes duplicates by default(But i dont want to remove duplicates)

Tags: python, dictionary, hash, duplicates

Python dictionary removes duplicates by default But i dont want to remove duplicates

Program

```
s = {"a":"s","a":"b","b":"d"}
print s
```

Output

```
{'a': 'b', 'b': 'd'}
```

Output which is expected

```
{'a':'s','a':'b','b':'d'}
```

Comment: Dictionaries can only map keys to a value if those keys are unique; what would `s['a']` return otherwise? If you need to associate multiple values per key, use *lists or sets* for the values.

Answer (score 1):

You should consider using other structure. Dictionary is a key-value so for each key there is only 1 value.
Try using either list of tuples or for each key in dict store a list of values.